# Loading images from resource don't work(C++ Dll)

Tags: c++, dll, resources, icons, logitech

I'm writing a Logitech plugin for MusicBee.
The only problem I have is that the images of the artwork, play and pause image don't load.
I have tested a lot of different ways to use the images in the VS2012 resource file. But non of them works. I must load images in a dll file and the image must be HICON or HBITMAP.
Below is een full class of my project. Full project can be found at [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/jimmyD/musicbee-logitech-applet/src).

```
//This is the code I have used for loading an image.
    playIcon = LoadIcon (GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
playIconHandle = m_lcd.AddIcon(playIcon, 16, 16);
m_lcd.SetOrigin(playIconHandle, 2, 2);



 //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Logitech File
    // C++ Source - Logitech.cpp - version 2012 v1.0
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Include Files
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "Logitech.h"

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Logitech methods
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------

    //This LogitechObject is a instance of the Logitech class for using in the thread
    Logitech * Logitech::LogitechObject;

    Logitech::Logitech():   stopthread(false), firstTime(true), position(0), duration(0)
    {
        LogitechObject = this;
    }

    Logitech::~Logitech()
    {
        stopthread = true;
        this->state = StatePlay::Undefined;
        timerThread.detach();
    }

    bool Logitech::getFirstTime()
    {
        return firstTime;
    }

    //Initialise Logitech LCD
    BOOL Logitech::OnInitDialog()
    {
        HRESULT hRes = m_lcd.Initialize(_T("MusicBee"), LG_DUAL_MODE, FALSE, TRUE);

        if (hRes != S_OK)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        m_lcd.SetAsForeground(true);

        //Create home screen Logitech Color LCD
        if(m_lcd.IsDeviceAvailable(LG_COLOR))
        {
            m_lcd.ModifyDisplay(LG_COLOR);
            m_lcd.SetBackground(RGB(245,245,245));
            logo = m_lcd.AddText(LG_STATIC_TEXT, LG_BIG, DT_CENTER, LGLCD_QVGA_BMP_WIDTH);
            m_lcd.SetOrigin(logo, 0, 50);
            m_lcd.SetText(logo, _T("MusicBee"));
            m_lcd.SetTextFontColor(logo, RGB(0,0,0));
            m_lcd.Update();
        }

        //Create home screen Logitech Monochrome LCD
        else if(m_lcd.IsDeviceAvailable(LG_MONOCHROME))
        {
            m_lcd.ModifyDisplay(LG_MONOCHROME);
            logo = m_lcd.AddText(LG_STATIC_TEXT, LG_BIG, DT_CENTER, LGLCD_BW_BMP_WIDTH);
            m_lcd.SetOrigin(logo, 0, 5);
            m_lcd.SetText(logo, _T("MusicBee"));
            m_lcd.Update();
        }

        //Start thread
        timerThread = thread(&Logitech::startThread);

        return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
    }

    //Create playing screen for Logitech Monochrome LCD
    VOID Logitech::createMonochrome()
    {
        m_lcd.RemovePage(0);
        m_lcd.AddNewPage();
        m_lcd.ShowPage(0);

        if (logo != 0)
        {
            delete logo;
            logo = 0;
        }

        artist = m_lcd.AddText(LG_SCROLLING_TEXT, LG_MEDIUM, DT_CENTER, LGLCD_BW_BMP_WIDTH);
        m_lcd.SetOrigin(artist, 0, 0);

        title = m_lcd.AddText(LG_SCROLLING_TEXT, LG_MEDIUM, DT_CENTER, LGLCD_BW_BMP_WIDTH);
        m_lcd.SetOrigin(title, 0, 13);

        progressbar = m_lcd.AddProgressBar(LG_FILLED);
        m_lcd.SetProgressBarSize(progressbar, 136, 5);
        m_lcd.SetOrigin(progressbar, 12, 38);

        time = m_lcd.AddText(LG_STATIC_TEXT, LG_SMALL, DT_LEFT, 80);
        m_lcd.SetOrigin(time, 12, 29);

        time1 = m_lcd.AddText(LG_STATIC_TEXT, LG_SMALL, DT_LEFT, 80);
        m_lcd.SetOrigin(time1, 125, 29);

        playIcon = static_cast<HICON>(LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_PNG2), IMAGE_BITMAP, 16, 16, LR_MONOCHROME));
        playIconHandle = m_lcd.AddIcon(playIcon, 16, 16);
        m_lcd.SetOrigin(playIconHandle, 2, 29);

        firstTime = false;
        changeArtistTitle(this->artistString, this->albumString, this->titleString, this->duration, this->position);
    }

    //Create playing screen for Logitech Color LCD
    VOID Logitech::createColor()
    {
        m_lcd.RemovePage(0);
        m_lcd.AddNewPage();
        m_lcd.ShowPage(0);

        if (logo != 0)
        {
            delete logo;
            logo = 0;
        }

        //background.LoadFromResource(NULL, AfxGetInstanceHandle(), IDB_G19BACKGROUND, _T("PNG"));
        //HBITMAP bmpBkg_ = background.GetHBITMAP();
        //m_lcd.SetBackground(bmpBkg_);

        m_lcd.SetBackground(RGB(184,220,240));

        artist = m_lcd.AddText(LG_SCROLLING_TEXT, LG_MEDIUM, DT_CENTER, LGLCD_QVGA_BMP_WIDTH);
        m_lcd.SetOrigin(artist, 5, 5);
        m_lcd.SetTextFontColor(artist, RGB(0,0,0));

        album = m_lcd.AddText(LG_SCROLLING_TEXT, LG_MEDIUM, DT_CENTER, LGLCD_QVGA_BMP_WIDTH);
        m_lcd.SetOrigin(album, 5, 30);
        m_lcd.SetTextFontColor(album, RGB(0,0,0));

        title = m_lcd.AddText(LG_SCROLLING_TEXT, LG_MEDIUM, DT_CENTER, LGLCD_QVGA_BMP_WIDTH);
        m_lcd.SetOrigin(title, 5, 55);
        m_lcd.SetTextFontColor(title, RGB(0,0,0));

        time = m_lcd.AddText(LG_STATIC_TEXT, LG_SMALL, DT_LEFT, 80);
        m_lcd.SetOrigin(time, 5, 80);
        m_lcd.SetTextFontColor(time, RGB(0,0,0));

        time1 = m_lcd.AddText(LG_STATIC_TEXT, LG_SMALL, DT_LEFT, 40);
        m_lcd.SetOrigin(time1, 275, 80);
        m_lcd.SetTextFontColor(time1, RGB(0,0,0));

        progressbar = m_lcd.AddProgressBar(LG_FILLED);//320×240 pixel color screen
        m_lcd.SetProgressBarSize(progressbar, 310, 20);
        m_lcd.SetProgressBarColors(progressbar, RGB(25,71,94),NULL);
        m_lcd.SetOrigin(progressbar, 5, 100);

        /*playIcon = static_cast<HICON>(LoadImage(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_PNG1), IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, LR_COLOR));
        playIconHandle = m_lcd.AddIcon(playIcon, 16, 16);
        m_lcd.SetOrigin(playIconHandle, 5, 29);*/

        firstTime = false;
        changeArtistTitle(this->artistString, this->albumString, this->titleString, this->duration, this->position);
    }

    void Logitech::startThread()
    {
        while(!LogitechObject->stopthread)
        {
            this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::milliseconds(500) );

            if(!LogitechObject->stopthread && LogitechObject->progressbar != NULL)
            {
                //Update progressbar and position time on the screen after 1 second of music.
                if(LogitechObject->state == StatePlay::Playing)
                {
                    this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::milliseconds(500) );
                    LogitechObject->position++;
                    float progresstime = ((float)LogitechObject->position / (float)LogitechObject->duration)*100;
                    LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetProgressBarPosition(LogitechObject->progressbar, static_cast<FLOAT>(progresstime));
                    LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetText(LogitechObject->time, LogitechObject->getTimeString(LogitechObject->position).c_str());
                }

                //If music stopped then the progressbar and time must stop immediately
                else if(LogitechObject->state == StatePlay::Stopped)
                {
                    LogitechObject->position = 0;
                    LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetProgressBarPosition(LogitechObject->progressbar, 0);
                    LogitechObject->m_lcd.SetText(LogitechObject->time, LogitechObject->getTimeString(LogitechObject->position).c_str());
                }

                LogitechObject->m_lcd.Update();
            }
        }
    }

    void Logitech::changeArtistTitle(wstring artistStr, wstring albumStr, wstring titleStr, int duration, int position)
    {
        this->artistString = artistStr;
        this->albumString = albumStr;
        this->titleString = titleStr;
        this->durationString = getTimeString(duration/1000);
        this->position = position;
        this->duration = duration/1000;

        if(!firstTime)
        {
            if(m_lcd.IsDeviceAvailable(LG_COLOR))
            {
                m_lcd.SetText(album, albumStr.c_str());
            }


            m_lcd.SetText(artist, artistStr.c_str());
            m_lcd.SetText(title, titleStr.c_str());
            m_lcd.SetText(time, getTimeString(position).c_str());

            string s( durationString.begin(), durationString.end() );

            if(s.size() < 5)
            {
                s = "0" + s;
            }

            wstring ws( s.begin(), s.end() );

            m_lcd.SetText(time1, ws.c_str());
            ws.clear();

            ///*playIcon = static_cast<HICON>(LoadImage(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_PNG1), IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, LR_COLOR));
            //playIconHandle = m_lcd.AddIcon(playIcon, 16, 16);
            //m_lcd.SetOrigin(playIconHandle, 5, 29);*/

            m_lcd.Update();

            artistStr.clear();
            albumStr.clear();
            titleStr.clear();

        }
    }

    //Set current playing position
    void Logitech::setPosition(int pos)
    {
        this->position = pos/1000;
        m_lcd.SetText(time, getTimeString(this->position).c_str());
        m_lcd.Update();
    }

    void Logitech::setDuration(int duration)
    {
        this->duration = duration/1000;
        m_lcd.SetText(time1, getTimeString(this->duration).c_str());
        m_lcd.Update();
    }

    //Change play state of the current playing song
    void Logitech::changeState(StatePlay state)
    {
        this->state = state;

        if(state == StatePlay::Playing && firstTime)
        {
            if(m_lcd.IsDeviceAvailable(LG_COLOR))
            {
                createColor();
            }

            else if(m_lcd.IsDeviceAvailable(LG_MONOCHROME))
            {
                createMonochrome();
            }
        }
    }


    //Change int of time to string
    wstring Logitech::getTimeString(int time)
    {
        string minutes = to_string((int)time /60);
        string seconds = to_string((int)time%60);

        if(minutes.size() < 2)
        {
            minutes = "0" + minutes;
        }

        if(seconds.size() < 2)
        {
            seconds = "0" + seconds;
        }

        string timeString = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        return wstring( timeString.begin(), timeString.end() );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), ...)
```

This cannot be correct in a plugin.  GetModuleHandle(NULL) returns a handle to the EXE, not your DLL.  Assuming you embedded your resources in your plugin DLL, you will need to use the module handle for your DLL, the one you get handed to you in your DllMain() function, 1st argument.

Comment: i have changed my code to:, `code` playIcon = LoadIcon (GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));`code`, and it doens't work.

Comment: @TestJef Try and read the answer again. You need to pass the module handle of your DLL. Passing `NULL` is no good.

Comment: Ans what to do if I don't have a DllMain()? I use a def file and so there is no DllMain.

Comment: Can you load an image from a disk in a Dll file? That can solve the problem.

Comment: A better question. Is it possible to use HBITMAP in a C++ Dll without using HINSTANCE? I need HBITMAP for the Logitech SDK.

Comment: You can't have a DLL without `DllMain`. But if you don't have access to it, and you are compiling with VS, you can get your `HINSTANCE` like this: `(HINSTANCE)__ImageBase`.